# slick track | how to set first element in slider with start content width

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

For slider we use slick

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

variable width

```js
        var disqus_shortname = 'slickcarousel';

        (function () {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
```

```html
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/css/prism.css" />
    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/js/native.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <div class="slider variable-width">
                <div style="width: 200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p>200</p>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p>175</p>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p>150</p>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p>300</p>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p>225</p>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 200px;background-color:red;">
                    <p>125</p>
                </div>

            </div>
      
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/js/prism.js"></script>
```

currently output is:
[image]

how to set always first item start with the same width at start content?

except result:
[image]

Comment: Please add you JS code as well related to the slider.

Comment: @PrerakSola we add link to js code in question     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/js/scripts.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You should have JS code similar to this:

```
<script>
$('.variable-width').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true
});
</script>
```

Here are some live examples. These examples may vary slightly from your uploaded files on Disqus, but the comparisons should help.

[codepen examples](https://codepen.io/crux1/pen/eYjMYRb)